# Laravel Validator: same not working

Tags: php, validation, laravel-4

I am using Laravel and validation:

```
    $validator = Validator::make(
        array('password' => $input['account_password']),
        array('password' => 'same:plain_text_password')
    );

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        $response = ['success' => false, 'errors' => $validator->messages()];
        return $response;
    }
```

If I use the same input in both fields, it returns as a fail, yet if I provide no input for the password field / different data then it returns true?

What happening here?

Comment: Why are you doing a plain text password at all????

Answer (score 1):

Your validator array names are wrong. You've used `password` twice:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
        array('account_password' => $input['account_password']),
        array('password' => 'same:account_password')
    );
```

Comment: @Lovelock - did that answer your question? Do you need any more info?